# Compact film camera to handle high iso sensitivity

Tags: equipment-recommendation, film, compact-cameras, high-iso, film-cameras

I'm an amateur photographer digging into film photography. I currently own a Minox GT which I really love: it's on aperture priority, really compact and light-weight, it's got a quite good, fast lens, and I don't bother the viewfinder build at all.

*However*, there's a flaw: the Minox GT handles films with iso sensitivity "only" **up to 800**, which is far below what I may want to bring my camera with me in the evening or in average bright home interiors.

I've tried to do some research but either I can't find maximum iso sensitivity of the camera, or the ones I find are well-known pricey cameras (such as the ricoh gr).

Therefore, I'd rather some **equipment recommendation**, since I'm looking for a camera which is

- **Compact**: I mean,  no 35mm camera is smaller than the Minox, but *large-pocket-sized* would be very good
- **Aperture priority** or even manual (but an internal exposimeter would be good in that case) but not a point-and-shoot like for example the Olympus Miu
- Able to **handle *at least* 3200 sensitivity**
- **Relatively cheap**: for example, in general, *rangefinder and viewfinder cameras kept a fair price* throughout these years
- **Not fundamental, but very important**: a built-in exposimeter, as my primary use of the camera would be street or city-lit night photography

**Does a camera with these features really exist?**

---

On a side note, is there some sort of an  online archive with camera models listedwith the main features?

Comment: Does your minox have exposure compensation? If so, you could dial in a -2 stop adjustment and set the ISO to 800 for correct exposure with  ISO 3200 film.  You could also look at using a separate meter with a camera that allows manual exposure settiing.  (Maybe something like the little Rollei (B35 or 35B? I forget) though the solar cell based meter wasn't great for low light use so you'd probably still need an separate meter).

Comment: @JerryTheC unfortunately nope, its exposure compensation is just +1. Anyway, I tried the separate meter setup: it's a little slow but decent, and actually that Rollei is a pretty good camera. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Leica Minilux and Contax T2 both could fit, depending on what you mean by "large pocket-sized" and "relativley cheap". They both have aperture priority and go up to ISO 5000. The Minilux may be to big and brick-shaped for you, the T2 may be too expensive.